# Странные вычисления C#

Tags: c#

Есть класс:

```
class outDemo
{
    public int getOut(double a,out double arg)
    {
        int whole = (int)a;
        arg = a - whole;
        return whole;
    }
}
```

А это создание его экземпляра и вызов метода:

```
outDemo od = new outDemo();
int number;
double arg;
number = od.getOut(10.025,out arg);
Console.WriteLine("Целая часть: " + number);
Console.WriteLine("Дробная часть: " + arg);
```

Просто возвращается целая и дробная части числа. Не пойму почему целое часть возвращается правильно, а именно **10**, а вот  дробная вместо **0.025** возвращается в примерно таком виде **0.0250000000000000004**. Откуда взялось 4?

Comment: Прошу прощения за индусский код, это просто в качестве примера для рассмотрения работы модификатора out.

Comment: @Grundy да, моя вина, как теперь мой вопрос закрыть? и спасибо за ссылку, изучу сейчас.

Comment: Уже пометили как дубликат, больше можно ничего не делать :)